# Odd System.Format Exception

Tags: c#, string.format

I am just trying to build a json string for my unit test and unexpectedly the following code returns system format exception. The error message indicates that it is trying to parse date which is quite odd to me. I am not asking to parse date.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(GetJson());
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static string GetJson(string dateStr = "", string lta = "5.25")
    {
        return String.Format("[{\"dateBooking\":\"{0}\",\"lta\":\"{1}\"}]", dateStr, lta);
    }
}
```

It can be easily reproduced but I am adding exception details:

> "An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format."

Comment: Add the exception details

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to escape the `{` with `{{` and the `}` with `}}` because `String.Format` will search for an argument like `{0:000}` but instead finds `{"dateBooking ... }` which is no valid argument format. Thats why a FormatException raises.

```
return String.Format("[{{\"dateBooking\":\"{0}\",\"lta\":\"{1}\"}}]", dateStr, lta);
```

Comment: Cool, it worked, I will mark it as an answer in 6 minutes. But, I think exception message is misleading.

Comment: The exception message is `Input string was not in a correct format.` and because you are supplying an format string as first parameter it needs to be formatted the right way.

Comment: I personally use Resharper and it tells me the following: `Format item index must be a number starting 0 without any leading or trailing whitespaces` I would recommend installing  Resharper (its not free, but it is worth it) when you are often working with C#

Comment: In error message details, it also mentions DateTime conversion error which is quite irrelevant. I am already using ReSharper, I just missed that warning.

Comment: The error itself does not mention any `DateTime` errors.  Are you looking under the 'Troubleshooting Tips'? Because these just show general error handling tips to the `FormatException`

Comment: Opps, yes you right.